# Eclipse crashes when closing a project

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse-indigo

I am using eclipse indigo in ubuntu 11.10

My java is

```
java version "1.6.0_06" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.6.0_06-b02) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0-b22, mixed mode)
```

I have two project open in my eclipse and it crashes when i try to close any of these projects.  Whenever a crash happens i have a hs_err_pidXXXX[X].log file in my home folder which is around 100k.

How should i debug and fix this problem? I couldn't find any duplicate threads for this.

I have copied my hs_err_pid21233.log to [google docs link here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JxowBeh-Y0WcqPFFZe9x8eswnrRiWP0bQfvBDgKN68c/edit?pli=1)

I tried the suggestion by @spektom.  Now eclipse crashes with a different error [attached here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qj2GOnak-TrRIjAa97PouvQZFTco4JWH0gzFHIJgyK0/edit?pli=1)

Comment: what about the hs_err_pidXXXX[X].log file. Eclipse will write the error into it.

Comment: What does the log file say? Run `less hs_err_pidXXXX[X].log` from the terminal.

Comment: it has a lot of data in different sections (Threads/ processes/ system) which i couldn't understand.  If you can tell me how i should get to the error i can update this post with that error message.

Comment: I guess the projects in the workspace are broken. Can you delete them and check them out or import them again?

Comment: I have uploaded my hs_err.pid to google docs. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JxowBeh-Y0WcqPFFZe9x8eswnrRiWP0bQfvBDgKN68c/edit?pli=1

Comment: @whirlwin i have uploaded my hs_err.pid file. let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I always find similar problems by "googling" for problematic frame code (in your case it's: [libjvm.so+0x1f125a]). This may bring you to existing bug reports either in Eclipse or in Java, which contain useful comments about workarounds and information in which version a bug is fixed.

For your specific problem, I've found these pages:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/0IGmtBE8nuQ

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/206620

**Workaround**: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/174759

Please go ahead and try if they work for you!

Comment: I had previously closed my project my moving the .project file to .project.bak


When i try to open the project now, after downgrading the startup vm to 1.5.15, my eclipse crashes.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qj2GOnak-TrRIjAa97PouvQZFTco4JWH0gzFHIJgyK0/edit?pli=1


I am googling with libjvm.so for any bugs/workarounds. Please let me know if you got any workaround too.