# Eclipse IDE shuts down frequently

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I've been trying to use the Eclipse 22.3.0-887826 SDK bundle to learn about android develeopment, however the IDE shuts down frequently. This happens a lot but mostly when cut/copy/paste are being used.

I've also tried the Eclipse 22.0.4-741630 version also, but still have the same issue.

I've also tried to "unbind" the items in preferences, but the problem still occurs the same way.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, latest Java JDK (7u45 32-bit)

Anyone else having this problem? I'm new to this so any suggestions to help resolve this is greatly appreciated. It's hard to focus on programming/learning when the IDE keeps crashing. :(

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x063792f2, pid=7516, tid=7404
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x063792f2
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0243bc00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7404, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x06840000

Registers:
EAX=0x067c0a01, EBX=0x00000236, ECX=0x067416cf, EDX=0x067c0bb3
ESP=0x0018e284, EBP=0x0000046e, ESI=0x06840000, EDI=0x0683fef4
EIP=0x063792f2, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0018e284)
0x0018e284:   0018e2a8 067c0590 06384574 0aa72c48
0x0018e294:   063795ef 067c0590 00358df8 00358e18
0x0018e2a4:   00358e18 0018e2d4 770d9993 0aa72c48
0x0018e2b4:   0243bc00 b123ff58 b123ff58 00000003
0x0018e2c4:   003b074e 00358dc0 00358e18 00000002
0x0018e2d4:   0018e30c 1002d46c 0250a9dd 0243bd30
0x0018e2e4:   0018e314 0243c354 0018e2ec b123ff58
0x0018e2f4:   0018e318 b1244d68 00000000 b123ff58 

Instructions: (pc=0x063792f2)
0x063792d2:   f2 fd ff 84 c0 74 5d 0f b7 0d 70 45 38 06 2b fb
0x063792e2:   8d 14 38 2b cf 8b 3d 68 45 38 06 8d 34 4f 8b ca
0x063792f2:   f3 a4 a1 68 45 38 06 8d 3c 02 b8 e8 03 00 00 66
0x06379302:   a3 70 45 38 06 eb 24 8d 4c 2d 00 e8 c5 f1 fd ff 

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x067c0a01 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000236 is an unknown value
ECX=0x067416cf is an unknown value
EDX=0x067c0bb3 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0018e284 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0243bc00
EBP=0x0000046e is an unknown value
ESI=0x06840000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x0683fef4 is an unknown value

Stack: [0x00090000,0x00190000],  sp=0x0018e284,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x063792f2

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.OleFlushClipboard()I+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.dnd.Clipboard.dispose()V+39
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClipboardOperationAction.doCutCopyWithImportsOperation()V+274
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClipboardOperationAction.internalDoOperation()V+36
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClipboardOperationAction$1.run()V+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+116
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClipboardOperationAction.run()V+53
j  org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+1
j  org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(Lorg/eclipse/core/commands/ExecutionEvent;)Ljava/lang/Object;+73
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Ljava/util/Map;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;Lorg/eclipse/core/expressions/IEvaluationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+107
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
J  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute()Ljava/lang/Object;
J  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;+13
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(Lorg/eclipse/core/commands/ParameterizedCommand;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+118
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(Lorg/eclipse/core/commands/ParameterizedCommand;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)Z+66
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(Ljava/util/List;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)Z+77
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(Ljava/util/List;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+14
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+172
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/bindings/keys/KeyBindingDispatcher;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+2
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+13
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;Z)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(IIIILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)Z+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(IIII)Z+32
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(III)Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/LRESULT;+61
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(II)Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/LRESULT;+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(II)Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/LRESULT;+3
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(IIII)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(IIII)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(IIII)I
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/MSG;)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V+606
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+256
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+108
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x05e15c00 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5720, stack(0x0bee0000,0x0bfe0000)]
  0x05e11c00 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7332, stack(0x0baa0000,0x0bba0000)]
  0x05e13c00 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1680, stack(0x0b960000,0x0ba60000)]
  0x05e15400 JavaThread "Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=8172, stack(0x0b730000,0x0b830000)]
  0x05e14c00 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=6168, stack(0x0b5f0000,0x0b6f0000)]
  0x05e14800 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=7128, stack(0x0b3b0000,0x0b4b0000)]
  0x05e14000 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=7436, stack(0x0b120000,0x0b220000)]
  0x05e13400 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=7444, stack(0x0a8d0000,0x0a9d0000)]
  0x05e0fc00 JavaThread "LogCat output receiver for 9a0e64cf" [_thread_blocked, id=7112, stack(0x0a790000,0x0a890000)]
  0x05e13000 JavaThread "Device Client Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=816, stack(0x0a020000,0x0a120000)]
  0x05e12800 JavaThread "Device List Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=7172, stack(0x09ee0000,0x09fe0000)]
  0x05e12000 JavaThread "Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=5212, stack(0x09d00000,0x09e00000)]
  0x05e11400 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=5960, stack(0x09870000,0x09970000)]
  0x05e11000 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4128, stack(0x09730000,0x09830000)]
  0x05e10800 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4352, stack(0x09230000,0x09330000)]
  0x05e10400 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4028, stack(0x07fe0000,0x080e0000)]
  0x06aee400 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=6588, stack(0x07ee0000,0x07fe0000)]
  0x0691b800 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=5132, stack(0x07de0000,0x07ee0000)]
  0x05ddb000 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=4208, stack(0x06640000,0x06740000)]
  0x05c7dc00 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7084, stack(0x06440000,0x06540000)]
  0x05c18000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7216, stack(0x061c0000,0x062c0000)]
  0x05bc3000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5980, stack(0x06080000,0x06180000)]
  0x05bc3c00 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1360, stack(0x05f80000,0x06080000)]
  0x04d35000 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=2940, stack(0x059d0000,0x05ad0000)]
  0x04bdcc00 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4468, stack(0x05330000,0x05430000)]
  0x023c6000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3628, stack(0x051f0000,0x052f0000)]
  0x023c5000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5136, stack(0x050b0000,0x051b0000)]
  0x023c2000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7292, stack(0x04f70000,0x05070000)]
  0x023b5400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5804, stack(0x04e70000,0x04f70000)]
  0x023b0400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3416, stack(0x04d70000,0x04e70000)]
=>0x0243bc00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7404, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]

Other Threads:
  0x023af000 VMThread [stack: 0x049b0000,0x04ab0000] [id=6164]
  0x04bee400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x05470000,0x05570000] [id=3980]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 69888K, used 3497K [0x7fff0000, 0x84bc0000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 62144K,   5% used [0x7fff0000, 0x8035a7e8, 0x83ca0000)
  from space 7744K,   0% used [0x83ca0000, 0x83ca0000, 0x84430000)
  to   space 7744K,   0% used [0x84430000, 0x84430000, 0x84bc0000)
 tenured generation   total 155048K, used 93028K [0x8fff0000, 0x9975a000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 155048K,  59% used [0x8fff0000, 0x95ac90c8, 0x95ac9200, 0x9975a000)
 compacting perm gen  total 56832K, used 56668K [0xafff0000, 0xb3770000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 56832K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb37471e8, 0xb3747200, 0xb3770000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0x04500000,0x04790000] byte_map_base: 0x04100080

Polling page: 0x00550000

Code Cache  [0x02500000, 0x02dd8000, 0x04500000)
 total_blobs=4401 nmethods=4164 adapters=170 free_code_cache=23740Kb largest_free_block=24300480

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 71.708 Thread 0x023c6000 4285   !         org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode$NodeList::newCursor (50 bytes)
Event: 71.708 Thread 0x023c6000 nmethod 4285 0x02dd1e48 code [0x02dd1f60, 0x02dd2248]
Event: 71.709 Thread 0x023c6000 4286             org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode$NodeList$Cursor::<init> (15 bytes)
Event: 71.709 Thread 0x023c6000 nmethod 4286 0x02dd23c8 code [0x02dd24c0, 0x02dd2550]
Event: 71.710 Thread 0x023c6000 4287   !         org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode$NodeList::releaseCursor (41 bytes)
Event: 71.710 Thread 0x023c6000 nmethod 4287 0x02dd2588 code [0x02dd26a0, 0x02dd28e8]
Event: 71.712 Thread 0x023c6000 4288             org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.AccessRuleSet::getViolatedRestriction (94 bytes)
Event: 71.712 Thread 0x023c6000 nmethod 4288 0x02dd29c8 code [0x02dd2af0, 0x02dd2ce8]
Event: 71.713 Thread 0x023c6000 4289             org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodBinding::getName (56 bytes)
Event: 71.714 Thread 0x023c6000 nmethod 4289 0x02dd2ec8 code [0x02dd3000, 0x02dd3284]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 19.145 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=48 (full 9):
 def new generation   total 54976K, used 54976K [0x7fff0000, 0x83b90000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 48896K, 100% used [0x7fff0000, 0x82fb0000, 0x82fb0000)
  from space 6080K, 100% used [0x835a0000, 0x83b90000, 0x83b90000)
  to   space 6080K,   0% used [0x82fb0000, 0x82fb0000, 0x835a0000)
 tenured generation   total 121912K, used 75397K [0x8fff0000, 0x976fe000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 121912K,  61% used [0x8fff0000, 0x94991750, 0x94991800, 0x976fe000)
 compacting perm gen  total 50688K, used 50612K [0xafff0000, 0xb3170000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 50688K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb315d218, 0xb315d400, 0xb3170000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 19.163 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=49 (full 9):
 def new generation   total 54976K, used 5920K [0x7fff0000, 0x83b90000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 48896K,   0% used [0x7fff0000, 0x7fff0000, 0x82fb0000)
  from space 6080K,  97% used [0x82fb0000, 0x83578260, 0x835a0000)
  to   space 6080K,   0% used [0x835a0000, 0x835a0000, 0x83b90000)
 tenured generation   total 121912K, used 81160K [0x8fff0000, 0x976fe000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 121912K,  66% used [0x8fff0000, 0x94f320c0, 0x94f32200, 0x976fe000)
 compacting perm gen  total 50688K, used 50612K [0xafff0000, 0xb3170000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 50688K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb315d218, 0xb315d400, 0xb3170000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 33.127 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=49 (full 9):
 def new generation   total 54976K, used 54816K [0x7fff0000, 0x83b90000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 48896K, 100% used [0x7fff0000, 0x82fb0000, 0x82fb0000)
  from space 6080K,  97% used [0x82fb0000, 0x83578260, 0x835a0000)
  to   space 6080K,   0% used [0x835a0000, 0x835a0000, 0x83b90000)
 tenured generation   total 121912K, used 81160K [0x8fff0000, 0x976fe000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 121912K,  66% used [0x8fff0000, 0x94f320c0, 0x94f32200, 0x976fe000)
 compacting perm gen  total 51712K, used 51585K [0xafff0000, 0xb3270000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 51712K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb32506e0, 0xb3250800, 0xb3270000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 33.140 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=50 (full 9):
 def new generation   total 54976K, used 3727K [0x7fff0000, 0x83b90000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 48896K,   0% used [0x7fff0000, 0x7fff0000, 0x82fb0000)
  from space 6080K,  61% used [0x835a0000, 0x83943ed0, 0x83b90000)
  to   space 6080K,   0% used [0x82fb0000, 0x82fb0000, 0x835a0000)
 tenured generation   total 121912K, used 86781K [0x8fff0000, 0x976fe000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 121912K,  71% used [0x8fff0000, 0x954af7b8, 0x954af800, 0x976fe000)
 compacting perm gen  total 51712K, used 51585K [0xafff0000, 0xb3270000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 51712K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb32506e0, 0xb3250800, 0xb3270000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 33.819 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=50 (full 9):
 def new generation   total 54976K, used 37782K [0x7fff0000, 0x83b90000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 48896K,  69% used [0x7fff0000, 0x821319d0, 0x82fb0000)
  from space 6080K,  61% used [0x835a0000, 0x83943ed0, 0x83b90000)
  to   space 6080K,   0% used [0x82fb0000, 0x82fb0000, 0x835a0000)
 tenured generation   total 121912K, used 86781K [0x8fff0000, 0x976fe000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 121912K,  71% used [0x8fff0000, 0x954af7b8, 0x954af800, 0x976fe000)
 compacting perm gen  total 53248K, used 53247K [0xafff0000, 0xb33f0000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 53248K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb33efe50, 0xb33f0000, 0xb33f0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 33.973 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=51 (full 10):
 def new generation   total 68736K, used 0K [0x7fff0000, 0x84a80000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 61120K,   0% used [0x7fff0000, 0x7fff0000, 0x83ba0000)
  from space 7616K,   0% used [0x83ba0000, 0x83ba0000, 0x84310000)
  to   space 7616K,   0% used [0x84310000, 0x84310000, 0x84a80000)
 tenured generation   total 152552K, used 91529K [0x8fff0000, 0x994ea000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 152552K,  59% used [0x8fff0000, 0x95952710, 0x95952800, 0x994ea000)
 compacting perm gen  total 53248K, used 53247K [0xafff0000, 0xb33f0000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 53248K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb33efe50, 0xb33f0000, 0xb33f0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 49.627 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=51 (full 10):
 def new generation   total 68736K, used 61120K [0x7fff0000, 0x84a80000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 61120K, 100% used [0x7fff0000, 0x83ba0000, 0x83ba0000)
  from space 7616K,   0% used [0x83ba0000, 0x83ba0000, 0x84310000)
  to   space 7616K,   0% used [0x84310000, 0x84310000, 0x84a80000)
 tenured generation   total 152552K, used 91529K [0x8fff0000, 0x994ea000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 152552K,  59% used [0x8fff0000, 0x95952710, 0x95952800, 0x994ea000)
 compacting perm gen  total 56320K, used 56187K [0xafff0000, 0xb36f0000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 56320K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb36cecd8, 0xb36cee00, 0xb36f0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 49.652 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=52 (full 10):
 def new generation   total 68736K, used 7616K [0x7fff0000, 0x84a80000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 61120K,   0% used [0x7fff0000, 0x7fff0000, 0x83ba0000)
  from space 7616K, 100% used [0x84310000, 0x84a80000, 0x84a80000)
  to   space 7616K,   0% used [0x83ba0000, 0x83ba0000, 0x84310000)
 tenured generation   total 152552K, used 91707K [0x8fff0000, 0x994ea000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 152552K,  60% used [0x8fff0000, 0x9597ec18, 0x9597ee00, 0x994ea000)
 compacting perm gen  total 56320K, used 56187K [0xafff0000, 0xb36f0000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 56320K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb36cecd8, 0xb36cee00, 0xb36f0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 67.482 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=52 (full 10):
 def new generation   total 68736K, used 55977K [0x7fff0000, 0x84a80000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 61120K,  79% used [0x7fff0000, 0x82f2a410, 0x83ba0000)
  from space 7616K, 100% used [0x84310000, 0x84a80000, 0x84a80000)
  to   space 7616K,   0% used [0x83ba0000, 0x83ba0000, 0x84310000)
 tenured generation   total 152552K, used 91707K [0x8fff0000, 0x994ea000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 152552K,  60% used [0x8fff0000, 0x9597ec18, 0x9597ee00, 0x994ea000)
 compacting perm gen  total 56832K, used 56590K [0xafff0000, 0xb3770000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 56832K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb3733830, 0xb3733a00, 0xb3770000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 67.656 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=53 (full 11):
 def new generation   total 69888K, used 0K [0x7fff0000, 0x84bc0000, 0x8fff0000)
  eden space 62144K,   0% used [0x7fff0000, 0x7fff0000, 0x83ca0000)
  from space 7744K,   0% used [0x83ca0000, 0x83ca0000, 0x84430000)
  to   space 7744K,   0% used [0x84430000, 0x84430000, 0x84bc0000)
 tenured generation   total 155048K, used 93028K [0x8fff0000, 0x9975a000, 0xafff0000)
   the space 155048K,  59% used [0x8fff0000, 0x95ac90c8, 0x95ac9200, 0x9975a000)
 compacting perm gen  total 56832K, used 56590K [0xafff0000, 0xb3770000, 0xcfff0000)
   the space 56832K,  99% used [0xafff0000, 0xb3733830, 0xb3733a00, 0xb3770000)
No shared spaces configured.
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 51.995 Thread 0x05e11c00 Threw 0x80d56668 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 51.995 Thread 0x05e11c00 Threw 0x80d569b8 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 51.995 Thread 0x05e11c00 Threw 0x80d56ea8 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 51.995 Thread 0x05e11c00 Threw 0x80d571f0 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 56.817 Thread 0x05e14000 Threw 0x8128c210 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 56.822 Thread 0x05e14000 Threw 0x8145dc60 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 58.227 Thread 0x0691b800 Threw 0x8028c2a8 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 58.232 Thread 0x0691b800 Threw 0x81d874f0 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 62.485 Thread 0x05e11400 Threw 0x82493670 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 62.490 Thread 0x05e11400 Threw 0x826b8228 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591

Events (10 events):
Event: 67.482 Executing VM operation: GenCollectFull
Event: 67.656 Executing VM operation: GenCollectFull done
Event: 67.656 loading class 0x02333300
Event: 67.657 loading class 0x02333300 done
Event: 67.657 loading class 0x023332d8
Event: 67.657 loading class 0x023332d8 done
Event: 67.657 Thread 0x05e16000 Thread added: 0x05e16000
Event: 67.657 Thread 0x05e16000 Thread exited: 0x05e16000
Event: 72.512 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 72.513 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done

Dynamic libraries:

0x72000000 - 0x7200d000     C:\Eclipse 22.3.0-887826
...

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m -Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826 -XX:MaxPermSize=512M 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic
```

Comment: When eclipse shuts down there will be a hs_err pid file.  I had similar problems a few months back.  Check this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010444/eclipse-crashes-when-closing-a-project ) and let me know if it helps.  Otherwise can you upload hs_err files so that we can debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as an Administrator

Comment: I've tried the following:
- Run as Administrator
- Updated my mouse/keyboard software
- Tried "Unbind Command" in Eclipse (General -> Keys)
- 32 & 64 bit versions (with appropriate versions of Java i.e. Eclipse x64 with Java 7u45 x64, etc.)
- Time it takes til shutdown varies, i.e. running for a few seconds to several minutes.
- Looked at the hs_err_pidxxxx.log file (not a clue here)

Comment: Not sure where I can upload the hs_err_pidxxxx.log.
ExceptionCode=0xc0000005 seems to be present in all the files (at least the ones I've looked at)

Comment: Yep, uninstalled everything, cleaned my system with registry cleaner as well as temporary file cleaner, reinstalled everything; still same results.

Comment: Can you uninstall all versions of Java (And old ones too), and put on the latest 64-bit release?

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue with eclipse juno. i uninstalled it and download latest version of eclipse. update SDK and additionally download android support repository from Android SDK Manager. now it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known JVM bug in C2 compiler: JDK-8154831.

Try adding the following JVM argument:

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.TypeConverter::*
```